# How to create second row in Custom ListView dynamically populated by Contacts?

Tags: android, contacts, custom-lists

I have following code for fetch contact detail from local DB and assigning the name and number to Custom ListView

```
public class Rabtaye extends Activity {

    ListView msgList;
    ArrayList<MessageDetails> details;
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;

    Cursor cursor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_main);

        msgList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MessageList);
        details = new ArrayList<MessageDetails>();

        MessageDetails Detail = new MessageDetails();

        // String info[] = { Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER, Phone._ID };
        String number = null;
        String name = null;
        try {

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
                    null);
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String contactId = cursor.getString(cursor
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String hasPhone = cursor
                        .getString(cursor
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                if (hasPhone.equals("1")) {
                    // You know it has a number so now query it like this
                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = " + contactId, null, null);
                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        number = phones
                                .getString(phones
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        name = phones
                                .getString(phones
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        System.out.println(number);

                    }
                    Detail.setName(name);
                    Detail.setNumber(number);
                    details.add(Detail);
                    msgList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(details, this));
                    phones.close();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        // Detail.setName(name);
        // Detail.setNumber(number);
        // details.add(Detail);

        msgList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                TextView s = (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.name);
                String abc = s.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(Rabtaye.this, abc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

CustomAdapter is passed to ListAdapter.
I have tried adding Name and Number within while loops too but every time only one name and number is populated into ListView. I am little confuse over this. Kindly help!

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you bind a Cursor to a ListView. In general, you only need a custom ListView if you need to generate one UI field from more than one cursor column, or if you need to process the column data before you bind it to a field.

CursorAdapter binds a Cursor to a ListView, but you also need to specify an "item layout" that defines the form of each entry or item in the ListView. For each row in the Cursor, the CursorAdapter binds the columns you want from the Cursor to the fields you have in the item layout. The item layout can occupy more than one line of the UI screen; all you need to do is define it that way.

I think what you're trying to do is display a contact name and a phone number for each contact that has a phone number. The best way to do that is to restrict the contents of your Cursor, rather than filtering the data once you have the Cursor.

The catch is that a single contact may have more than one phone number. For *that*, you may need to have a custom *adapter* that programmatically adds phone number views to a parent view. This would allow you to display the name once, along with all of the phone numbers.

Comment: Thanks for anwsering, but I am little confuse what you are saying. Can you please show me how it is done. Thanks.